# how to check if DTO has the expected data types in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, api

i have a webapi done in .net. I would like to verify the data the user inserts has the expected data type. Here is my DTO:

```
    public class EditHash
{
    public EditHash()
    {
    }
    public string? UrlShort { get; set; }
    public string? UrlOrigin { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpireAt { get; set; }
}
```

and here is how i tried to verify the data type :

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> ModifyUrl(string hash, [FromBody] Request.EditHash h )
    {
if(!(h.ExpireAt is DateTime) ||  !(h.UrlShort is string))
        {
            gc.errorNumber = "505";
            gc.value = "Bad Request";
            gc.detail = "One or many parameters data type are not correct";
            return new TimeoutExceptionObjectResult(error: gc, 400);
        }
    }
```

i also tried with this method :

```
if(h.ExpireAt.GetType()!=typeof(DateTime) || h.UrlOrigin.GetType()!=typeof(string) ||h.UrlShort.GetType()!= typeof(string))
        {
            ...
        }
```

in the both cases, when i insert an integer instead of a string for instance, the code does not returns the error i defined. How can i verify the data type ?

Comment: In your class, the property `ExpireAt` is always a `DateTime` - the condition can never be false`. I assume you parse some string and create your object from that. This is the place in your code where you have to do those checks. Can you show how you do this?

Comment: i don't do any other check apart from the one i explain in my question. but apart from the datetime, if we have to verify the varibale inserted  is really a string as expected, how can i do?

Comment: You need to check against null values, ie: h.ExpireAt != null
Also here -> public string? UrlShort { get; set; } , string? makes no sense, string is nullable by itself

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the user can call your API (and get a controlled response) with 'incorrect' values; you need a more 'permissive' data structure as input then you can check the values an cast to the real DTO:

```
public class EditHash_Permissive_Input
{
    public string UrlShort { get; set; }
    public string UrlOrigin { get; set; }
    public string ExpireAt { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the exposed method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ModifyUrl(string hash, [FromBody] Request.EditHash_Permissive_Input h )
{
if(!DateTime.TryParse(h.ExpireAt, out DateTime dateTimeInput) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(h.UrlShort)) //<- Add other desired validations to url as "1" is a string and could not be a valid url
    {
        gc.errorNumber = "505";
        gc.value = "Bad Request";
        gc.detail = "One or many parameters data type are not correct";
        return new TimeoutExceptionObjectResult(error: gc, 400);
    }
    else
    {
         Request.EditHash internalValue = new Request.EditHash() 
            {
                UrlShort = h.UrlShort,
                UrlOrigin = h.UrlOrigin,
                ExpireAt = dateTimeInput,
            }
         //Continue with what you mean to do with h data
    }
}
```